# Smooth curves in Bertini's theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective irreducible surface and $|D|$ be a globally generated linear system. If $|D|$ is positive dimensional, then Bertini's theorem says that we can choose a smooth curve say $C \in |D|$  (a general member of $|D|$).

My question is that, in that theorem can we always choose the curve $C$ in such a way that $C$ is reduced and irreducible (or at least reduced for example on a smooth $K3$ surface) ?

Can someone point out an argument or an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For instance, let $X = \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ and consider the linear system of the line bundle $\mathcal{O}(2,0)$.

Comment: thanks. Can we take $C$ to be reduced? (at least on a $K3$ surface)? Is there a condition which ensures that in particular situation we can take $C$ to be such?

Comment: also what happens if on a $K3$ surface $|D|$ is a positive dimensional ample linear system?

Comment: If $C$ is smooth (and Bertini's theorem proves the existence of smooth $C$), it is reduced. And if $|D|$ is ample, any divisor in it is connected, and smooth + connected implies irreducible.

Comment: Just to make sure that I have understood it correctly : Bertini says that on a smooth projective surface (not necessarily $K3$) if $|D|$ is base point free and positive dimensional, then one can choose an effective divisor $C \in |D|$ which is smooth and is therefore reduced curve. Moreover if $|D$ is ample, our effective divisor $C$ is both reduced and irreducible (on any smooth surface, not necessarily $K3$). Please  correct me if some part of this understanding is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, that's right.